# Expression is typed incorrectly Error in a DB that has been working fine for years

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am looking at an MS Access 2010 DB which was designed by someone who left the company years ago. The DB has been in use for years and is split into a Front and Backend.

Now one of the reports in the DB, called via a Macro (not VBA), produces the following error:

> This expression is typed incorrectly, or it is too complex to be
>   evaluated

The error implies that there is a mistake in the SQL, so that is where I decided to look first. However, the front and backend are both saved as `.ACCDE` Files, so it's not possible that any user messed up or changed anything.

When I examined the reports `record source`, the query executes fine, and I can see results. Here is the SQL:

```
SELECT [Reporting of Cases].[Case File No],
       [Reporting of Cases].[Date of relevance],
       [Reporting of Cases].Report,
       [Reporting of Cases].[Reported by],
       [Reporting of Cases].[Division Report],
       [Case Database].[Headline (Report)],
       [Case Database].[Case Description (Report)],
       [Case Database].Category,
       [Case Database].Division,
       [Case Database].Organisation,
       [Case Database].Location,
       [Case Database].[CHF at Risk],
       [Case Database].[Risk Flag],
       [Case Database].[Open Date],
       [Reporting of Cases].[Group Report],
       [Reporting of Cases].ID
FROM [Case Database]
  INNER JOIN [Reporting of Cases] 
    ON [Case Database].[Case File No] = [Reporting of Cases].[Case File No]
WHERE ((([Reporting of Cases].[Date of relevance]) BETWEEN Date() AND Date()-45)
  AND (([Reporting of Cases].ReportFlag)=TRUE))
ORDER BY [Reporting of Cases].[Date of relevance] DESC,
         [Reporting of Cases].ID DESC;
```

The filter used to open the report looks fine as well:

```
[Date of relevance] Between Date() And Date()-6
```

It is only when I try to call up the report, regardless of whether I do it manually or via macro, that it produces that error message.

**What could cause this sudden error message?** This is one of many reports in the DB and the others continue to function as expected.

**UPDATE:**
I have checked the underlying table to ensure that the field `Date of relevance` is stored as a date. It is and all data entered in the current records is stored as a date as well.

Comment: Try to check the data in [Date of relevance], it may contain corrupted data

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Is there an intelligent way of going about that? I have literally thousands of records.

Comment: I have just examined the underlying table in which `Date of relevance` is stored, and it has a format of `medium date` with a default value of `today()`, so this would probably preclude nonsense from being entered. Or do you think that there might still be a way?

Comment: Does the error occur on all computers / for all users? If not, simply copying a fresh copy of the frontend to the computer may help. BTW, queries *can* be edited in an .accde

Comment: The error occurs for all users on all computers. Ok. Did not know that that was possible with .accde. However, given the people using the DB I doubt that they would how to change a query, much less know that.

Comment: What is data type of column with date? If text, then here may be in issue. Check dates using query with `IsDate` function

Comment: All records have the data type "date".

Comment: To check the [Date of relevance] values, sort the table in datasheet view first ascending, then descending, and check the min/max values. But if the query runs fine... does the report have additional grouping / sorting levels?

Comment: Does each user have their own, local frontend copy? Or do they all run the same network frontend? The latter is considered bad practice, in this case consider restoring a backup or creating a new .accde frontend from its .accdb.

Comment: They all use the same network frontend. The report does indeed create additional groupings: it groups first on `date of relevance` then on `Headline (report)`.

Comment: What impact does it have that they all use the same network front end? I thought that opening a front end was like opening a template where each user essentially was working on his own copy

Comment: No, each local Access process works with the network file. Impact: more chances for problems / corruption, less performance. If a "fresh" frontend works: there is your reason. :) If not, it was worth a try.

Comment: As this DB was locked with .ACCDE I had to first get an unlocked version to investigate the issue. Theoretically, this would be a "fresh" version. Unfortunately, it has the same problem. I'm stumped. PS: I would move this to a discussion thread, but the corporate internet policy blocks the word "chat" in the URL. Also, thank you for all your help thus far!

Comment: Out of ideas. :( Steps to manually debug: Make a copy of frontend & backend, relink tables from backend copy, remove filters/groupings until the report starts working. Or delete most of the data (was the report slow before it stopped working?)

Comment: Thank you Andre! I will do as you suggested... if / when I find it, i'll report back so you know what it was as well! This will likely take a while.

Comment: Just noticed something: `WHERE [Date of relevance] BETWEEN Date() AND Date()-45` -- is this a typo, or has this ever worked? Because for BETWEEN, the dates must be in the correct order, `BETWEEN earlier_date AND later_date`. Yours is reversed.

Comment: Are both [Case Database] and [Reporting of Cases] tables? Or queries? You say the query runs ok. When you run the query, did you visit the last row, last column? That sometimes makes a difference. Having the issue suddenly appear indicates either corruption which has already been mentioned, or something with the data. Try running the report with an older date range. Look for formulas in the report's control sources or groupings. As for the order of dates with 'BETWEEN', Access (unlike SQL Server) has always been forgiving of that.

Comment: Thank you for all your help! To answer your last question @Andre, the WHERE clause was written like that and it worked fine. However, I don't see it being a double negative in my system... maybe something got messed up copying it to SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking Andres suggestion, I examined the report further, by deleting controls out of the report. Once the control that was linked to `[Case Description (Report)]` field in the underlying query was deleted, the report started working again.

Upon examining the records that were linked to that particular control, one that was recorded recently, stuck out from the rest.

The issue was caused by that text field that was in one of the underlying tables. In one of the records in the DB, the field called `[Case Description (Report)]` contained only

> `#DELETE`

as the entry text. That particular field in the record seemed to remain blocked. I couldn't or delete anything in the field.

Once the entire record was deleted (and afterwards manually reentered without the delete) the DB started to work again!

Comment: That's probably a Memo column? Sounds a light case of database corruption. I suggest doing the steps in http://allenbrowne.com/recover.html

Comment: And if this isn't an isolated case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/252357/3820271 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/827596/3820271

Comment: It was indeed a memo field. Thank you for those pointers! Interesting to learn what the actual problem was.